# extracting data from xmlNodeSet R

Tags: xml, r

I have a XmlNodeSet (XML Package, R programming language) and I have to extract data. This is how it looks:

```
<drugScores>
            <drug code="3TC" score="95" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="ABC" score="110" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="ATV/r" score="90" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="AZT" score="140" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="D4T" score="150" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="DDI" score="135" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="DRV/r" score="0" levelStanford="1" levelSIR="S" />
            <drug code="EFV" score="100" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="ETR" score="40" levelStanford="4" levelSIR="I" />
            <drug code="FPV/r" score="55" levelStanford="4" levelSIR="I" />
            <drug code="FTC" score="95" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="IDV/r" score="85" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="LPV/r" score="75" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="NFV" score="120" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="NVP" score="150" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="RPV" score="45" levelStanford="4" levelSIR="I" />
            <drug code="SQV/r" score="105" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="TDF" score="85" levelStanford="5" levelSIR="R" />
            <drug code="TPV/r" score="35" levelStanford="4" levelSIR="I" />
        </drugScores>
```

I have to do the matrix, dataFrame or sth, which contains drug code, score, levelStanford, levelSIR. Can you help me?

Comment: Apply xmlAttrsToDataFrame to the xmlNodeSet `lapply(x["//drugScores"], XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
kk<-read_html("yourxml.xml") %>%
html_nodes("drug") 
ss<-do.call(rbind,(lapply(c("code","score","levelStanford","levelSIR"),function(i)data.frame(cbind(type=i,values=html_attr(kk,i))))))
head(ss)
  type values
1 code    3TC
2 code    ABC
3 code  ATV/r
4 code    AZT
5 code    D4T
6 code    DDI
```